# Replacing ezXML

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

We have been tasked to replace ezXML library on a Android with C++ project because some vulnerabilities have been identified and additionally the community is no longer supporting it.

What library is a good replacement choice ?

Any suggestions or advice regarding the replacement ?

Comment: If you want to find any library in c++, I'll suggest to check boost first.

Comment: the C++ code is inside an Android project. I dont know if we are able to include boost.
Can it be done with boost ?

Comment: If you have platform limitation, please edit your question and elaborate on limitation. Also it's not actually on-topic on SO because it's opinion-base.

Comment: i have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

A really nice and fast XML library is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTD-XML
It can work with really huge XML files (256 GB XML files).

There is just one thing to mention: no new versions since 2016 / 2017.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/files/vtd-xml/ximpleware_2.12/VTD-XML%20Standard%20Edition/